# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError showing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My controller has:

```
def create
  @todo=Todo.new(params[:todo]).save
  redirect_to todos_path
  end
end
```

My model has:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base               
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to strong parameters in rails 4 being the default.

A simple fix for this code is to have:

```
  @todo= Todo.new(params[:todo].permit(:description)).save
```

in the controller

Comment: You should have a method in your controller named `todo_params` that returns the params Hash with permitted & without excluded params.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the permit! method, which will add to whitelist an entire hash of parameters. It's described in [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). But it's not recommended.